# Is possible to set the home screen programmatically?

Tags: android, homescreen

I have set my app as home screen(), so when i clik in home button the system let me to choose between default home screen and my app. I choose my app, it's ok. But when a user change a setting i need to change the home screen to default (system home screen) without choosing it, directly. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the home screen programmatically: you must provide the user with an option to choose which launcher they want to use.

I ran into a similar issue when developing a soft keyboard for Android.  Since you can't set the default keyboard, I showed a dialog which allowed the user to pick my keyboard during setup.  I then verified that my keyboard was now the default before moving forward in the setup wizard.

Basically, the best you can do is show the dialog chooser to allow the user to choose the default system home screen.

Comment: Thanks,

How could i launch the chooser of home screen when i want. I'm usin:
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.clearPackagePreferredActivities("com.dm.prado");
I have two problems:
The chooser is only showed when i press home button, i want to show it when i want.
when i choose home screen first time the launcher is never showed again.

Comment: The problem is that when i set a home screen as default the system never ask for what app i want to be as home screen. I solve this issue when i stablish my app as defaul, because i cann clear do .clearPackagePreferredActivities. The problem is when i stablish home phone screen as default, becausa i can't reset it by code.

Comment: So you need to set your app as the default home screen when another app is already the default?

Comment: Yes. I set my app as home in manifest. If i change the default screen to a different screen than my app after i install my app then i cannot return to set my app as default home screen.

Comment: And clearing the defaults from your app does not allow the user to select a launcher next time they press home, correct?

Comment: I clear the defaults of my app i this way: PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); pm.clearPackagePreferredActivities("com.dm.prado"); But, how i could clear the defaults of the home screen of the phone when it is the default. I don't know if it's other way of clearing the settings. do you know?

Comment: I don't know, but I'd try emailing the developers of Nova Launcher.  It has a button in settings to select the default launcher that works regardless of the current default home, which seems to be exactly what you're needing.

Comment: Also (not sure if you can do this), but for the keyboard you can get the default keyboard in settings.  So if you can get the default launcher package name from settings you might be able to clear it in the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, IrAndroid. The problem for clearing other package is that i obtain a permission error (android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS. I have included this permnission in my app). Maybe i'm doing something wrong, but i have readen in other forum questions that probably it's not possible to clear a exgernal package from my app.